# Rotate and translate a 2D point N times

Tags: c++, performance, coordinate-system

This is a C++ program that rotates a point initially located at origin by a given angle **A** (degree) counterclockwise and **L** translate its x-coordinate (sum L to it).

Here is my program:

Firstly it reads the number of test cases.
Each test case has 2 real numbers and 1 integer that represents a rotation, translation and how many times the operation of rotate and translate must be applied.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>


#define gc getchar_unlocked()
inline double getDouble() {
    double v;
    scanf("%lf",&v);
    return v;
}

#define CONST 0.01745329251994329576922 //3.14159265358979323846/180 = 0.01745329251994329576922
std::pair<double, double> rotate(std::pair<double, double> p, double a){
    double rad = a*CONST;
    return std::make_pair(p.first*std::cos(rad) - p.second*std::sin(rad), p.first*std::sin(rad) + p.second*std::cos(rad));
}


int main(void){
    int t = (int) getDouble();

    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        double a = getDouble(),l = getDouble();
        int v = (int) getDouble();

        std::pair<double, double> p(0,0);
        while (v--) {
            p = rotate(p, a);
            p.first += l;
         }
        //for cases like 30 1.5 121... the printf just put -0.00
        if(std::abs(p.first) < 0.005)
            p.first = 0;
        if(std::abs(p.second) < 0.005)
            p.second = 0;
        printf("%.2lf %.2lf\n",p.first,p.second);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

> 4
>   90 10 1
>   90 10 2
>   90 10 3
>   30 1.5 1000000000

Sample output:

> 10.00 0.00
>   10.00 10.00
>   0.00 10.00
>   3.55 3.55

How to make it faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly generate a matrix **T** that represents the rotation and translation for the values given.

[image: Matrix]

Here **xt** means the translation on x-coordinate value. **yt** is always 0 because there is no translation y-coordinate. **Theta** means the angle to rotate.

After that just do T'= T^v where v is the number of times that the operation of rotation and translation must be executed. T^v can be solved using exponentiation by squaring.

Finally multiply a vector 3x1 with values x y 1 (where x and y means the initial point in this case 0 0) representing the point with T'. The resulting vector of the multiplication has the answer.

The overall complexity of this solution is O(log(n)). Better than this O(n) solution.

Answer (score 3):

- `CONST` is not a name; it doesn't convey any meaning. Call it something like `rads_per_degree`. If you feel you need to comment on the value, better do the calculation explicitly (take advantage of \$\pi\$ being defined for you in `cmath`):

  ```
  const double rads_per_degree = M_PI / 180;
  ```
- Each time you rotate, you recalculate radian measure, `sin` and `cos`. Within the test case these values do not change. You may safely precompute them:

  ```
  double rads = rads_per_degree * angle;
  double sin = std::sin(rads);
  double cos = std::cos(rads);
  while (v--) {
      do_math(x, y, sin, cos, L);
  }
  ```
- I am not sure why you special cased small values.
- `getDouble` is somewhat dubious. It would've make sense to have such a function to sanitize input. As written, it is meaningless. Also, you should *not* read integer as double.

Answer (score 1):

**Style/Maintainability**

- You should always prefer the `const` keyword to a `#define`. This is because `#define` is a preprocessing statement that will do a blanket substitution of the value. This means that if you have a compile-time error in your code, you will see the # rather than your name for the number, which makes debugging much more difficult.
- Why not `template` your `rotate` function so that it can take `int` points and other `arithmetic` types to rotate? This would be a minimal change to make your function more flexible overall.
- No user prompt to go along with your `scanf`? Maybe you should use `argv` and just have your program take a command line argument when you start it?
- You need comments explaining what your functions do, and probably more descriptive function names. `getDouble` is a particularly bad function name because `double` is quite a generic word as is `get`.
- No need to `return 0` as this is done automatically nowadays.

**Efficiency**

- If you expect your users to do the same rotations repeatedly, you might consider using a `map` to store values you've already computed. Combine this with @vnp's suggestion to turn `sin` and `cos` into parameters for the function.

**Error checking**

- You should check values after you read them in to make sure you got what you want. I don't see any error checking in `getDouble`